# Python CLI fails silently on importing jwt

Tags: python, jwt, importerror, pyjwt, python-jose

I have installed in a virtualenv both `python-jose` (3.2.0) and `PyJWT` (2.0.1), but with both my console script fails  without any error message on importing `jwt`.

Even from the CLI (Python 3.7.7 on Windows 10), both

```
from jose import jwt
```

and

```
import jwt
```

make the CLI closes silently, without any error message.
[image]

Furthermore:

```
>>> import jose
>>> jose.jwt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'jose' has no attribute 'jwt'
```

`pip check` does not return any error. For everything else, the virtualenv seems to work just fine (it is a Flask app).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add screenshots, so that we can see it

Comment: Have you  tried: `from jose import jwt`?

That's what the pypi project page says: https://pypi.org/project/python-jose/

Comment: try install python-jose in virtualenv and path your interpreter to virtualenv then run your code

Comment: @Sinakzlca it is already in a virtualenv, sorry I didn't mention it before. I edited the post.

Comment: @astrochun yes, it is exactly what I did. I have added a gif showing the error.